# on() event handler for multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I'm using three instances of [ace editor](https://ace.c9.io/) in a form. I initialize them like so:

```
var before = ace.edit("beforeSQL", {
  showPrintMargin: false,
  fontSize: '14px',
  theme: "ace/theme/sqlserver",
  mode: "ace/mode/sql" 
}),
execute = ace.edit("executeSQL", {
  showPrintMargin: false,
  fontSize: '14px',
  theme: "ace/theme/sqlserver",
  mode: "ace/mode/sql" 
}),
after = ace.edit("afterSQL", {
  showPrintMargin: false,
  fontSize: '14px',
  theme: "ace/theme/sqlserver",
  mode: "ace/mode/sql" 
});
```

I then put a listener on each one to make sure there's content in each field before the user can click the submit button:

```
  before.session.on('change', () => {
    toggleSubmit();
  });
  execute.session.on('change', () => {
    toggleSubmit();
  });
  after.session.on('change', () => {
    toggleSubmit();
  });
```

The `toggleSubmit()` function enables the submit button when each editor stores a value.

Both sections of code feel redundant, but the second section is what really concerns me. Anyone know a clever way to whittle this down? For example is there a way I could do the following:

```
[before.session, execute.session, after.session].on('change', () => {
  toggleSubmit();
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Would you be able to [edit] your post to include the HTML, and perhaps more of the code around the sample JS above? That will give reviewers more context and hopefully the ability to give a better review.

Comment: Well, the code I'm writing doesn't really interact with the DOM directly. Each item is tied to an element like the following: `<div class="ace-editor"></div>`

Comment: What additional content do I need to provide? Would a jsfiddle work? I'm asking about syntax, not functionality.

Comment: You should add all the code necessary to the post... if you can get a jsfiddle running, then you should be able to put the code in a [runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - there is a keyboard shortcut: CTRL + M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var before = ace.edit("beforeSQL", {
  showPrintMargin: false,
  fontSize: '14px',
  theme: "ace/theme/sqlserver",
  mode: "ace/mode/sql" 
}),
execute = ace.edit("executeSQL", {
  showPrintMargin: false,
  fontSize: '14px',
  theme: "ace/theme/sqlserver",
  mode: "ace/mode/sql" 
}),
after = ace.edit("afterSQL", {
  showPrintMargin: false,
  fontSize: '14px',
  theme: "ace/theme/sqlserver",
  mode: "ace/mode/sql" 
});
```

There's a lot of repetition here in terms of the options you're using. You could avoid repeating yourself by creating an object to hold defaults. For example:

```
const defaults = {
  showPrintMargin: false,
  fontSize: '14px',
  theme: "ace/theme/sqlserver",
  mode: "ace/mode/sql" 
}

var before = ace.edit("beforeSQL", {...defaults})
var execute = ace.edit("executeSQL", {...defaults})
var after = ace.edit("afterSQL", {...defaults})
```

To avoid repeating yourself when adding an event listener you could do something like this:

```
[before, execute, after].forEach(obj => {
  obj.session.on('change', toggleSubmit);
})
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the calls to `.edit()` can be called without using the spread operator for the defaults into an extra JSON object: `var before = ace.edit("beforeSQL", defaults)`

Comment: or was there a reason to destructure those defaults into a separate copy for each editor?